# Selenium WebDriver Issue with cssSelector

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, selenium-rc

I am trying to click on a button with using a CSS selector in Selenium 2.0 WebDriver. The issue is the script which I am able to run with Selenium RC is not working with WebDriver. 
Code:

Selenium RC:

```java
selenium.click("css=.gwt-Button:contains('Run Query')");
```

which works absolutely fine.

Selenium WebDriver:

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gwt-Button:contains('Run Query')")).click();
```

which does not work.
I am using: selenium-server-standalone-2.9.0.jar with Firefox version 5.0. Could anyone help me in figuring out why the `cssSelector` is not working with WebDriver?

Comment: can you show the element that you are trying to select

Comment: <button type="button" class="gwt-Button" id="ext-gen362">Run Query</button>    But I can not use the ID as that is dynamically genaratetd.

Comment: @Swagatika: id is dynamically generated. Is full text of id generated dynamically? or is some last portion of id dynamically generated? here  id="ext-gen362" . If ext-gen is fixed and only value (362) is being changed then xpath with contains or starts-with can be used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Contains' is being deprecated from CSS 3. Webdriver supports whatever natively supported by the browser. It works in selenium RC because RC uses Sizzle library for css selectors and it supports 'contains'. Did you try something like,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gwt-Button[type='button']");
element.click();
```

If this is not unique then perhaps you might need to filter it further down. If your site uses jQuery then you could use 'contains' selector from jQuery.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
WebElement element = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return $(\".gwt-Button:contains('Run Query')\")[0];");
element.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep I could make it work by injecting sizzle library.

Comment: If your application uses jQuery then perhaps you don't need to inject sizzle library and pollute the DOM. AFAIK, sizzle is used as jQuery's CSS selector engine. In that case the second solution I mentioned could work out fine.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is my application does not use JQuery, thats why I had to use Sizzle separately and make the contains() method work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

that syntax looks valid and when I dropped some elements on a test page and then went to my console and did $(".gwt-Button:contains('Run Query')").length I got a 1 when I changed the text of the buttons.  So the only thing I can think of is maybe you have a Run Query button that exists on the page but isn't displayed and so you get the runtime exception.  You might want to do a check to see if it's displayed before clicking on it.  Or creating a list of the elements and then removing all hidden (display == false) elements.